# I'm trying to make a simple program that increses a number each time the user click on a button

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces

hi i'm trying to make a simple progrma that shows how many times a button is clicked on. I'm trying to learn to use namespaces. My problem is that then i click on the button the number that is displayed is just undefined.

```
        var $S = {};

    $S.antalClick = 0;

    $S.click = function() {

        $S.antalClick = +1;
            document.getElementById("visa").innerHTML = $S.antalCLick;
    }

<input type="button" value="click me" onClick=$S.click() /> <br/>
<div id="visa"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your $S.click function, replace

`$S.antalClick = +1;` by `$S.antalClick += 1;`

this is a shortcut to mean `$S.antalClick = $S.antalClick + 1`

Comment: Ah im so dumb i forgot about that im really new to learning programming . EDIT: ah silly me it was just a typo in document.getElementById("visa").innerHTML = $S.antalCLick;

Comment: Haha it's ok ? It works and is your html onclick attribute is good too ? Don't you need to put quotes and remove the majuscule ?

Comment: yes haha i changed $S.antalCLick to $S.antalClick i think that was my biggest problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten the previous answer further with `$S.antalClick++;`. The `++` signifies increasing a value by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$S.antalClick++;`:

```js
var $S = {};
$S.antalClick = 0;

$S.click = function() {
  document.getElementById( 'visa' ).innerHTML = $S.antalClick++;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onClick=$S.click() />
<div id="visa"></div>
```